# technique for creating tree diagrams with photos?

Tags: php, html, css, tree

I'm looking to create on-the-fly tree diagrams using PHP, HTML, and CSS. Mock-up below:

[image]

The images need to be clickable links, and I'd prefer not to use an image map as that would be costly for on-the-fly generation.

I was thinking of using some creative `<div>` placement like so:

[image]

where dotted lines represent invisible borders and solid lines visible ones. The html would be pretty gnarly, but the code to generate it should be a few clean loops only.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML structure you need to generate is a plain old nested list, e.g.:

```
<ul>
  <li>Group 1
    <ul>
      <li><a href="foo">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="bar">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Group 2
    <ul>
      <li><a href="baz">Item A</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Dead simple and you don't need to add any "gnarly" markup, or any markup at all. Use CSS to style each item accordingly. [Here's a tutorial](http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/). It's a little older, though—these days every modern browser supports `:last-child` so you don't need any JavaScript unless you're concerned about those IE6/7/8 users.

Comment: I knew about the list, but I didn't know you could get those nice lines, hence the box approach. Thank you for the extremely helpful link.

Comment: Glad to help. It's really just a matter of setting the right background image, margin, and padding. Good luck!